# What is the spirit in concept of the reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

We know how to get and consume the reputation, but what the spirit in concept of the reputation is?

Should I keep accumulating the reputation? Or consume it for mutually exchange of teaching and learning?

I [consumed my reputation on Stack Overflow for that use](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348176/ken-kin?tab=bounties), am I use it correctly?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reputation

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: Thanks. But I think [[How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)] might not be an answer for me of this question.

Comment: You can do with your reputation whatever you want. If you think those questions deserved bounties, by all means spend your rep. That's what the system is there for.

Comment: @Bart: Thank you. But I'm confused with the spirit of it. Should I accumulate it as possible or just spend it up? Which is the concept of it designed for?

Comment: That question does not have a definitive answer. You will have to answer that for yourself. You don't have to spend it on bounties, but if you think that's useful, go ahead. There are users who never offer a bounty on anything and have a significant amount of rep. But that does not mean they are doing something wrong. You're free to do with it as you please.

Comment: @Bart: ***You will have to answer that for yourself.*** seems I asked a unanswerable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reputation is a measurement for the amount of trust the community has in a user. Some people call it a measurement for the amount of popularity.

The spirit behind the concept is to get users involved and reward positive actions without exchanging goods and money. And as such it works great. Users struggle to be the first to answer a question because these tend to get the most upvotes (especially with easy questions).

You can use the reputation to better the site (with privileges), to brag (with flair) or to get more attention to a question (with a bounty).

Comment: Thank you very much. You might want to revise for typo of **attenton**. This question has been marked as duplicate and will get no more answers, though I think it's something different from the question it considered duplicate to.